# How can I optimize streaming a .osgb file into a ByteString efficiently?

Tags: java, protocol-buffers

I am sending a `.osgb` file in a Google Protobuf message which requires a Byte String.  It is encoded "ISO-5589-1".  In python, I can simply `open(file_name, "r").read()`.  In Java, I have very noob-ishly created:

```
    String model;

    ByteString modelBytes = null;

    try {
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream( filename );
        DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(fis);

        byte[] bytes = new byte[dis.available()];

        if ( dis.available() != 0 ) {
            dis.readFully(bytes);
        }
        model = new String(bytes, "ISO-8859-1"); 

        modelBytes = ByteString.copyFrom(model, "ISO-8859-1");
    }
```

I'm not looking to code-golf this excerpt, but I feel as though I have possibly redundant or extra code that is genuinely not needed.  It feels as though I should be able to just convert the data stream immediately into a ByteString and not worry about the encoding, but I'm not familiar enough with it.

I am very inexperienced with Java so I appreciate any assistance.  Thanks.

Comment: If you want to read it into a `ByteString`, then don't bother about the encoding -- you're currently just decoding and then immediately recoding.  Skip both parts and just put the bytes straight into the `ByteString`.

Comment: The API has this: https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/java/com/google/protobuf/ByteString.html#readFrom(java.io.InputStream)

Comment: I believe that's just what I'm looking for, thanks! Sorry for it being such a simple solution.